# Flutter, Carousel Text change with Image change

Tags: image, flutter, carousel

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Expanded(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 150.0,
        width: 300,
        child: Carousel(
          boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
          autoplay: true,
          animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          dotSize: 6.0,
          dotIncreasedColor: Colors.grey,
          dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
          dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
          dotVerticalPadding: 10.0,
          showIndicator: true,
          indicatorBgPadding: 7.0,
          images: [
            AssetImage('assets/mountain.jpg'),
            AssetImage('assets/mountain2.png')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  // Other children below
  ]
)
```

Hi, I've managed to implement a carousel but I am wondering how you can add Text to it on the center. When the carousel moves to a new image I want the text to change to. I am using carousel_pro 1.0.0.

Comment: Can you please share where is that `Carousel` Widget from? It seems to be taking Image objects directly instead of Widgets. If that's the case then you can't do what you want to do. But there might be other solutions. Please share the package you got Carousel from or the code you have to make it.

Comment: I have used carousel_pro 1.0.0

Comment: That package always expects you to give images to the carousel, not Widgets. I would advise you to try a different carousel package like `flutter_multi_carousel` or building our one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
`image` attribute actually can use `widget` , so you can use `Card`

code snippet

```
images: [
              Card(
                  child:
                      Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                const ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
                  subtitle:
                      Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
                ),
                Image.network(
                    'https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*GqdzzfB_BHorv7V2NV7Jgg.jpeg'),
              ])),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';

class CarouselPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 300.0,
          width: 300.0,
          child: Carousel(
            boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
            autoplay: false,
            animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
            dotSize: 6.0,
            dotIncreasedColor: Color(0xFFFF335C),
            dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
            dotPosition: DotPosition.topRight,
            dotVerticalPadding: 10.0,
            showIndicator: true,
            indicatorBgPadding: 7.0,
            images: [
              Card(
                  child:
                      Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                const ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
                  subtitle:
                      Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
                ),
                Image.network(
                    'https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*GqdzzfB_BHorv7V2NV7Jgg.jpeg'),
              ])),
              Card(
                  child:
                      Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                const ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
                  subtitle:
                      Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
                ),
                Image.network(
                    'https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*wnIEgP1gNMrK5gZU7QS0-A.jpeg'),
              ])),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CarouselPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is complete working code with Image on top with text and dots. For this you need to use these two libraries:- " carousel_slider: ^4.1.1 ", "smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2", update them to the latest.

```
  class MyItem {
  String itemName;
  String path;
  MyItem(this.itemName, this.path);
}

class craouselImage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _craouselImage createState() => _craouselImage();
}

class _craouselImage extends State<craouselImage> {
  int activeIndex = 0;
  List<MyItem> items = [
    MyItem("item 1", 'assets/images/appiconlogo.png'),
    MyItem("item 2", 'assets/images/Mockup4.png'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CarouselSlider.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 400,
              viewportFraction: 1,
              autoPlay: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
              autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 1),
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  activeIndex = index;
                });
              },
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
              final imgList = items[index];
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: buildImage(imgList.path, index)),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  buildText(imgList.itemName, index),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 22,
          ),
          buildIndicator(),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 22,
          ),

          //buildText(itemName, index),
          // buildText(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildImage(String imgList, int index) => Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Image.asset(
            imgList,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      );

  buildIndicator() => AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
        activeIndex: activeIndex,
        count: items.length,
        effect: const JumpingDotEffect(
            dotColor: Colors.black,
            dotHeight: 15,
            dotWidth: 15,
            activeDotColor: mRed),
      );

  buildText(String itemName, int index) => Align(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
      child: Text(
        itemName,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 23, color: mRed),
      ));
}
```